# append html node with multi input from value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want input to enter value number
and When entering the value will be create html node with input inside it

ex

```
<input>
```

and when enter value like 3

it will apper

```
<div><input id='input1-3'><input id='input1-3'><input id='input1-3'></div>
<div><input id='input2-3'><input id='input2-3'><input id='input2-3'></div>
```

thanx

Comment: You will post JavaScript/jQuery code, right?

Comment: yes i will use jQuery

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand question. You have 1 input box and when user enter number inside it, you want to display that number in another input box?

Comment: no i want display html node

Comment: like <div><input id='input1-3'><input id='input1-3'><input id='input1-3'></div>

Answer (score 1):

try this i think it will help you ,

```
<body>
<input type="text" id='inputnum'>
</body>
```

jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#inputnum').on('change',function(){
var a=parseInt($(this).val());
console.log(a);
for(var i=1;i<a+1;i++)
{
var divs='<div>' 
for(var j=1;j<a+1;j++)
{
divs=divs+'<input id="input'+i+'-'+j+'">';
}
divs=divs+'</div>';
$('body').append(divs);
}
})
});
```

Complete JSFiddle Example https://jsfiddle.net/Praveent696/7bt74fbj/

Comment: thanks that is help me but when i delete the number and enter another number but it supposed to delete the old fields and creates new fields

Comment: @haitham to remove all div when input change you can use $('div') .remove(); , if this really help you plz upvote

Comment: when i arrive to 15 question i'll upvote ... thanx for help :)

Comment: @haitham now check this fiddle , i think it will full fill your requirement https://jsfiddle.net/Praveent696/7bt74fbj/3/

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you want to do, i think that you just have to use append function like this.

```
<input id="input1">    
<script>
$(document).on("keypress", "input#input1", function() {
    var n = this.value;
  for (var i=0;i<n;i++){
    var x = document.createElement("input");
    x.setAttribute("id", "wathever");
    document.body.appendChild(x);    
  }     
    });
</script>
```